# Python Servers NoneType/float catch

Tags: python, server

I am testing server discrepancies on python. When I test using only 1 server, I get errors. is there a way to try/catch for this:

```
# Discrepancy = abs(this server's difference - average of differences of all the other servers

for server in server_time_differences:
    discrepancies[server] = abs(server_time_differences[server] - calc_average(server))
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
discrepancies[server] = abs(server_time_differences[server] - calc_average(server))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for any help, I am new to Python.

edit: Here is my calc_average function. I assume the try/except is incorrect

```
# Function that calculates average time difference for the servers
def calc_average(server_name):
#Temporarily copies time differences to use for this function
temp = server_time_differences.copy()
temp.pop(server_name)
sum_ = sum(temp.values())
# Average = sum of servers divided by number of used servers
try: 
    return sum_ / len(temp.keys())
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("error")
```

edit 2: New Errors 
ok so I am still gettin an error:

```
in calc_average return sum_ / len(temp.keys())
```

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
in <module> discrepancies[server] = abs(server_time_differences[server] - calc_average(server))
```

and

```
in calc_average raise RuntimeError ('No other servers to compare with ' %server_name)
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: do you see `error` printed out? if you catch the exception, you'll have to return something

Comment: no, error does not get printed out

Comment: is that the correct indentation level for `calc_average` or did it just get messed up when copied onto SO or ?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, it just messed up

Comment: Just messed up on SO*

Answer (score 2):

As your error message indicates, your call to `calc_average(server)` returns `None`, and your attempt to subtract its returning value from `server_time_differences[server]` fails because a floating number can't operate with `None`.

From your code for `calc_average` it's apparent that it would return `None` only when `ZeroDivisionError` occurs, since there is no explicit return statement in the `except` block. The reason you may not have noticed the message `'error'` being printed might be because it's mixed with the trace back for the `ZeroDivisionError` exception as standard error is unbuffered while standard output (where your `'error'` message goes) is buffered.

Due to the nature of the error, you should not return a value when `ZeroDivisionError` occurs, since no value would make sense for the caller to continue a meaningful calculation. Instead, it should re-raise a friendlier exception, and let the caller catch the exception and print the error message in a more graceful way:

```
def calc_average(server_name):
    temp = server_time_differences.copy()
    temp.pop(server_name)
    sum_ = sum(temp.values())
    try: 
        return sum_ / len(temp.keys())
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise RuntimeError('No other server available to calculate average server time difference with %s.' % server_name)

for server in server_time_differences:
    try:
        discrepancies[server] = abs(server_time_differences[server] - calc_average(server))
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Sorry am trying to post my calc_average function

Comment: Edited my original question if you don't mind looking at my calc_average function.

Comment: ok so I am still gettin an error:    
in calc_average return sum_ / len(temp.keys()) .    
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero  
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
in <module> discrepancies[server] = abs(server_time_differences[server] - calc_average(server))  

and  
in calc_average raise RuntimeError ('No other servers to compare with ' %server_name)  
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: I am just going to post the new errors in the original questions... *updated original question*

Comment: hmmm,,, I deleted the "%server_name"  and the error went away.

Comment: That was because you were missing the `%s` formatting placeholder at the end of the error message in my answer.